# SaSSified version of Skeleton CSS

Tags: css, sass

Recently I have been developing a SASSified version of Dave Gamache's [Skeleton CSS](http://getskeleton.com/) front-end framework. I have publicly posted the code on [github](https://github.com/atomicpages/skeleton-sass) as well as a [live demo](http://atomicpages.github.io/skeleton-sass).

What I am looking for is constructive feedback on my project as a whole and ways to improve/simplify features. I believe my solution is far more elegant and requires less time trying to figure out what file is where and what to edit. In addition to this, I have recreated a grid generator similar to 960.gs so users can customize their own grids.

Here are some relevant snippets of code and structure:

The main purpose of my SASS, SCSS, and Compass translation of the CSS framework is to better utilize the SASS CSS pre-processor. The project contains:

- **Compass** Translation which includes:

  - SASS (indented) syntax
  - SCSS (CSS) syntax
  - Utilization of Compass SASS framework to accomplish many tasks
- **SASS** Translation which includes:

  - SASS (indented) syntax
  - SCSS (CSS) syntax
  - Custom mixins in `_mixins` file to accomplish and automate many tasks

One major feature of my translation is that it comes with a grid creator similar to that of 960.gs where you have a fixed and fluid style grid. Here are some snippets from that grid creator:

```
// function to turn number to string for selectors
$ones: "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine";
$teens: "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen";
$tens: "", "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "nintey";
@function numToString($int) {
    $int: abs($int); // no nonnegative numbers
    $number: "";
    @if($int > 100) { // I'm sorry Dave; I can't let you do that.
        $number: "No numbers past 100";
    }
    $temp: $int / 10;
    $temp: floor($temp);
    @if($int >= 1 and $int <= 100) {
        @if($temp < 1) { // it's a one!
            $number: nth($ones, $int % 10);
        }
        @if($temp == 1) { // in the teen range
            // in the teen range
            @if($int % 10 == 0) {
                $number: "ten";
            } @else {
                $number: nth($teens, $int % 10);
            }
        }
        @if($temp >= 2 and $temp <= 9) { // more than our teens
            @if($int % 10 == 0) {
                // means it's a number evenly divisible by 10
                $number: nth($tens, $int / 10);
            } @else {
                $number: "#{nth($tens, floor($int / 10))}-#{nth($ones, $int % 10)}";
            }
        }
        @if($temp == 10) { // this is the end...
            $number: "one-hundred";
        }
    } @else {
        $number: "Invalid parameter passed. Number must be between 1 and 100."
    }
    @return $number;
}
```

and the mixin:

```
@mixin grid($width: $baseWidth, $fluid: $isFluid, $colWidth: $baseColWidth, $gutterWidth: $baseGutterWidth, $colCount: $baseColCount) {
    @if ( $fluid == true ) {
        // and for you math heads... a_n = (100n / $colCount) - 2
        // where n is the iteration
        @include _fluidGrid($colCount);
    } @else {
        // and for you math heads... a_n = 40 + ( 60 ( n - 1 ) )
        // where 40 = column width
        // where 60 is the consistent difference between each column
        // where n is the iteration
        @include _fixedGrid($width, $colWidth, $gutterWidth, $colCount);
    }
}
// "PRIVATE" MIXINS - these are mixins the help separate logic and should never be used outside of the grid mixin
// generate the fluid grid
@mixin _fluidGrid($colCount, $unit: "%") {
    // override only for fluid
    /* Overrides */
    .container {
        .column,
        .columns {
            margin: {
                left: 1%;
                right: 1%;
            }
        }
    }
    /* The Grid */
    .container {
        @for $i from 1 through $colCount {
            @if ( $i == 1 ) {
                .#{numToString($i)}.column,
                .#{numToString($i)}.columns { width: ( ( 100 * $i ) / $colCount ) - 2#{$unit}; }
            } @else {
                .#{numToString($i)}.columns { width: ( ( 100 * $i ) / $colCount ) - 2#{$unit}; }
            }
        }
        /* The Offsets */
        @include _offset($unit, $colCount, false);
    }
}

// generate the fixed grid
@mixin _fixedGrid($width, $colWidth, $gutterWidth, $colCount) {
    @if($gutterWidth != $baseGutterWidth) {
        /* Gutter Overrides */
        .container {
            .column,
            .columns {
                margin: {
                    left: $gutterWidth / 2;
                    right: $gutterWidth / 2;
                };
            }
        }
    }
    /* The Grid */
    .container {
        @for $i from 1 through $colCount {
             @if ( $i == 1 ) {
                .#{numToString($i)}.column,
                .#{numToString($i)}.columns { width: $colWidth; }
            } @else {
                .#{numToString($i)}.columns { width: $colWidth + ( ( $colWidth + $gutterWidth ) * ( $i - 1 ) ); }
            }
        }
        .one-third.column { width: ( $width / 3 ) - 20}
        .two-thirds.column { width: ( ( $width * 2 ) / 3 ) - 20 }
        /* The Offsets */
        @include _offset("px", $colCount, $colWidth);
    }
}

// generate the offset
// Note: although $colWidth is optional, it is REQUIRED by the fixed grid
@mixin _offset($unit, $colCount, $colWidth) {
    @if ( $unit == "%" ) {
        @for $i from 1 through ( $colCount - 1 ) {
            .offset-by-#{numToString($i)} { padding-left: ( ( 100 * $i ) / $colCount ) * $i#{$unit}; }
        }
    } @else {
        @for $i from 1 through ( $colCount - 1 ) {
            .offset-by-#{numToString($i)} { padding-left: ( $colWidth + 20 ) * $i; }
        }
    }
}
```